# how do I use make Ansible use ssh v1, as I get the below error

Tags: python-3.x, ssh, network-programming, ansible

```
23:41:37 $ansible all -i inventory -u user1 -m ping -k
SSH password:
<ip address> | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Protocol major versions differ: 2 vs. 1\r\n",
    "unreachable": true
}
```

while I do normal ssh from my host as below

```
23:41:37 $ ssh -1 user1@<"ip address">
```

I can explicitly specify to use ssh v1, but how do I do the same from Ansible?

Comment: Really do you want ssh v1? It's known to be unsafe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to edit your ansible.cfg file and add or edit the below part:

```
[ssh_connection]

# ssh arguments to use
ssh_args = -1
```

But the use of protocol version 1 is NOT RECOMMENDED for security reasons.

Protocol SSH1 is gone for good. It is removed from manual pages and documentation from recent distros.

Comment: Thank you. I know ssh -1 is unsafe, but this would be lab environment with old Cisco devices.